# Number of subgroups of $\mathbb Z _m \times \mathbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $\mathbb Z_m$ denote the additive group of residue classes modulo $m$.

Is there a closed form for the number of subgroups of $\mathbb Z_m\times\mathbb Z_n$?

Comment: If $a,b\neq 0$ are a generators of a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then $\{(a, 0),(0,b)\}$ is generator of a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$. And all subgroup except the trivial one is obtained this way.

Comment: @Azlif That's not true in general. It's only true if $\gcd(m,n)=1$, in which case the group is cyclic.

Comment: @DerekHolt having a set of generator with two elements means not cyclic at all.

For Example, in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ we have the sets of generator are $\{(1,0)\}, \{(0,1)\}, \{(0,2)\}, \{(1,2)\} \{(1,0),(0,1)\}, $ and $\{(0,0)\}$

Comment: Again, that is not true in general. ${\mathbb Z}_2 \times {\mathbb Z}_3$ has a set of generators with two elements, but it is cyclic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a closed form if you allow for sums: According to Theorem 3 from the paper [on the subgroups of the group $\mathbb Z_m\times\mathbb Z_n$](https://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/open_files/13485_121031-Toth-finalsubmission.pdf) by Mario Hampejs, Nicki Holighaus, László Tóth and Christoph Wiesmeyr, the number of subgroups of $\mathbb Z_m\times\mathbb Z_n$ is
$$\sum_{a|m\text{ and } b|n} \gcd(a,b)=\sum_{d|\gcd(m,n)} \phi(d)\tau\left(\frac md\right)\tau\left(\frac nd\right)=\sum_{d|\gcd(m,n)} d\cdot\tau\left(\frac{mn}{d^2}\right),$$

where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) and $\tau(n)$ is the [number of positive divisors of $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#%CF%83k(n),_%CF%84(n),_d(n)_%E2%80%93_divisor_sums).

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think that's a "closed formula", because it involves a summation. But it's probably as good as you will get!

Comment: @DerekHolt edited!