# Find the number of subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{p^3} \times \mathbb Z_{p^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is this: Find the number of subgroups $H$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} $, $p$ is the prime number,  $|H| = p^{2}$.

Here is my understanding:

Let's assume $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}  $ has a generator of $ (a,b), \,  a \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^3}, \, b \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}  $

$\mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} $ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{p^5} $  and cyclic group since  $\gcd( p^{3},p^{2}) \ne 1 $.

Now how can you find the subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb Z_{p^3} \times \mathbb Z_{p^2} $, when $H$ is just single number and  $ \\  \mathbb Z_{p^3} \times \mathbb Z_{p^2} $ is more like the coordinate (Not sure I put this right)

Comment: I am not sure how you're generating your $\LaTeX$ code, but please notice the difference between ```\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}``` which yields $\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$ and ```\mathbb Z_{p^2}``` which yields $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$. In the first, $p^2$ shows as $\mathbb{p^2}$ instead, because the brace delimiters for ```\mathbb``` include it.

Comment: Question is unclear. Are you asking for the number of subgroups of order $p^2$?

Comment: If you assume $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ has a generator,, then you are assuming a false statement. The group is not cyclic.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3400034/number-of-subgroups-of-mathbb-z-m-times-mathbb-z-n).

Comment: Care to engage with the people trying to help you, JJ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, mate. I got the clue from the Dietrich's post. Thank you for your time.